# InvalidTaskException when trying to get list of entities from a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a list of entities out of my MS Server Database using Entity framework 7 where the entities have a nested object and that object has also a nested object where I check on with a condition. My code looks like this:

```
List<MyObj> MyObjList = DbContext.MyObj.Include(x => x.MyNestedObj).ThenInclude(x => x.MyNestedNestedObj).Where(x=>x.MyNestedObj.MyNestedNestedObj.ID==SomeValue).ToList();
```

When I try this I get:

> InvalidTaskException cannot cast from
>   System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression to
>   System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression

I did this kind of thing several times in my project where I only have on level of nested object and there it works fine. It also works when I first get them all out and then sort with the condition like that:

```
List<MyObj> MyObjList = DbContext.MyObj.Include(x => x.MyNestedObj).ThenInclude(x => x.MyNestedNestedObj).toList();
List<MyObj> MyObjList2=MyObjList. Where(x=>x.MyNestedObj.MyNestedNestedObj.ID==SomeValue).ToList();
```

But I don’t want to get the whole table every time I do this I would like to do it in one step like the other places.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should replace your `Where` and `Include` method try it like this:

```
List<MyObj> MyObjList = DbContext.MyObj
    .Where(x => x.MyNestedObj.MyNestedNestedObj.ID == SomeValue)
    .Include(x => x.MyNestedObj)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.MyNestedNestedObj)
    .ToList();
```